# Error trying to publish a built-in read action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

I've been trying to publish a read action for an article object to timeline, but I can't get past this error:

Message (#3502) Object at url...has og:type of 'website'. The property 'article' requires an object of og:type 'article'. Now I am confident my meta tags are correct and the og:type is 'article', not 'website'.

Here is the link to the article http://fb.idebate.eu/article2.php.

Any help at all would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing your article against the [Facebook Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) it returned the following error:

> Parser Mismatched Metadata:
>
> The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched.

In your page, you've defined the article description twice:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="A Farewell To Arms" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="quote" />
```

Try removing one of the descriptions, and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've corrected it like you suggested but unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you include code that you are using, or a sample cURL request?

Comment: The entire code is in the code-behind of the url I posted. The facebook debugger is showing no errors or warnings but when I click the read button on my page I still get the same error message I described above.

Comment: I took another look. It turns out that you have a typo in your API request: You are calling `FB.api('me/news.reads'+'?article=http://fb.idebate.eu.article2.php&access_token=`, note the missing `/` following `fb.idebate.eu`, where you have a `.` instead.